# Place all distinct elements of the array to the left in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to write a programme that places all distinct elements of an array to the left of the same array, and all other (non-distinct) elements right after in whatever order. The time complexity must be O(n log n), i.e. using sorting and no additional array must be created. I made an attempt to print the distinct elements with the following code:

```
using System;  
using System.Diagnostics;
public class Program
{  
    public static void Main() 
    {
      int []arr = {1, 1, 6, 5, 4, 3, 4, 6, 1, 7, 2, 1, 4, 9};
      allDistinct(arr);
    }

     public static void allDistinct(int[] x)
     {
          int n = x.Length;
          Trace.Assert(n>0);

          Array.Sort(x); //O(n log n)

          for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
          {
               // Move the index ahead while 
               // there are duplicates
               while (i < n - 1 && x[i] == x[i + 1])
                    i++;
          }
          Console.WriteLine(x[i]);
    }
}
```

However, I'd like my function to be of the form

```
public static int[] allDistinct(int[] x)
```

and then use the auxiliary function to print the array in the Main()

```
printArray(allDistinct(arr));
```

where

```
public static void printArray(int[] array)
{
     for(int i=0; i<array.Length; ++i) 
     {
         Console.Write("" + array[i] + " ");
     }
     Console.WriteLine("");
 }
```

I made an attempt using the swap function, but I didn't succeed to get what I wanted, i.e. given the array

```
1 1 6 5 4 3 4 6 1 7 2 1 4 9
```

my output should be

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 9 + (duble elements in whatever order, e.g. 1 1 1 4 4 6)
```

thanks for your advise

Comment: Maybe a `List<int>` would be easier for what you want to do

Comment: Hint: Sort the array and then do TWO loops, the first scanning over it outputting each distinct value (ie. whenever it changes), the second outputting the non-distinct values (ie. after a change output each value that is the same). Use `IEnumerable` and `yield return` to make it easier to code. If you have to do it totally 'in place' consider having two pointers starting at each end, the left accepting unique values, the right accumulating the extra non-unique values.

Comment: Please clarify if the left part *must* be sorted (as answers show it isn't clear to everyone)

Answer (score 2):

I got a fully working [example](http://tpcg.io/ZXnL5z):

```
using System.IO;
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int[] array = {1, 1, 6, 5, 4, 3, 4, 6, 1, 7, 2, 1, 4, 9};
        allDistinct(array);
    }

    static int[] allDistinct(int[] array)
    {
        Array.Sort(array);
        printArray(array); // first step monitoring
        int n = array.Length;

        // iterate through array
        for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++)
        {
            // bubble push duplicates to the back
            while(array[i] == array[i+1])
            {
                for(int j=i+1;j<n-1;j++)
                {
                    array[j] = array[j+1];
                }
                array[n-1] = array[i];
                n--;
            }

            printArray(array); // loop steps monitoring
        }

        return array;
    }

    static void printArray(int[] array)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", array));
    }
}
```

This yields this output:

```
1 1 1 1 2 3 4 4 4 5 6 6 7 9 
1 2 3 4 4 4 5 6 6 7 9 1 1 1 
1 2 3 4 4 4 5 6 6 7 9 1 1 1 
1 2 3 4 4 4 5 6 6 7 9 1 1 1 
1 2 3 4 5 6 6 7 9 4 4 1 1 1 
1 2 3 4 5 6 6 7 9 4 4 1 1 1 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 9 6 4 4 1 1 1 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 9 6 4 4 1 1 1
```

---

Note that this will **change the order** of the original array **and** return it, as arrays can't be passed ***by value*** in C#.

---

Edit:

About the bubble-push, you could instead count the number of duplicates and push harder:

```
static int[] allDistinct2(int[] array)
{
    Array.Sort(array);
    printArray(array);
    int n = array.Length;

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        int countDup = 0;
        int iValue = array[i];

        // Count the number of duplicates
        for(int j=i+1;j<n && array[j] == iValue;j++)
        {
            countDup++;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("// " + countDup + " time(s) the value " + iValue);
        if(countDup > 0)
        {
            for(int j=i+1;j<n-countDup;j++)
            {
                array[j] = array[j+countDup];
            }
            for(int j=n-countDup;j<n;j++)
            {
                array[j] = iValue;
            }
        }
        n-=countDup;

        printArray(array);
    }

    return array;
}
```

This yields:

```
1 1 1 1 2 3 4 4 4 5 6 6 7 9
// 3 time(s) the value 1
1 2 3 4 4 4 5 6 6 7 9 1 1 1
// 0 time(s) the value 2
1 2 3 4 4 4 5 6 6 7 9 1 1 1
// 0 time(s) the value 3
1 2 3 4 4 4 5 6 6 7 9 1 1 1
// 2 time(s) the value 4
1 2 3 4 5 6 6 7 9 4 4 1 1 1
// 0 time(s) the value 5
1 2 3 4 5 6 6 7 9 4 4 1 1 1
// 1 time(s) the value 6
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 9 6 4 4 1 1 1
// 0 time(s) the value 7
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 9 6 4 4 1 1 1
// 0 time(s) the value 9
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 9 6 4 4 1 1 1
```

---

[Updated coding-ground link](http://tpcg.io/3NDARG)

Comment: *"Note that this will change the order of the original array and return it, as arrays can't be passed by value in C#."* nothing prevents you from creating and acting on a different copy of the array in the function.

Comment: @Pac0 nothing excepted requirements - *no additional array must be created*

Comment: @Rafalon that is correct, thanks! However what about the time complexity? We have O(nlogn) from sorting + O(n*n) right?

Comment: @mike.dl that sounds correct (well I'm no expert in time complexity, but it appears bubble sort is O(n²) so maybe using an O(nlogn) algorithm instead would give you what you want)

Answer (score 0):

> places all distinct elements of an array to the left of the same array

I don't see any requirement for the resultset to be sorted.  The only requirement is that the elements be arranged so that all duplicates come later than all distinct values.

If the resultset need not be sorted, there is no reason to call `Array.Sort()` (which is sort of cheating really); we can write our own solution that collates the numbers ourselves.

This algorithm flips the problem by starting at the end and looking for duplicates. When one is found, it is swapped into place, and the upper boundary of the array is moved downward. If the element at the end has no duplicates, we swap it with first element, and adjust the lower boundary upward so we don't look at it again.

```
public class Program
{
    public static int[] DistinctFirst(int[] arr)
    {
        var lbound = 0;
        var ubound = arr.GetUpperBound(0);
        var i = ubound;
        while ( i>lbound )
        {
            var k = i;
            for (int j=i-1; j>=lbound; j--)
            {
                if (arr[j] == arr[i])
                {
                    Swap(ref arr[j], ref arr[i-1]);
                    i--;
                }
            }
            if (k == i)
            {
                Swap(ref arr[i], ref arr[lbound]);
                lbound++;
            }
            else
            {
                i--;
            }
        }
        return arr;
    }

    public static void Swap(ref int a, ref int b)
    {
        int c = a;
        a = b;
        b = c;
    }

    public static void Main() 
    {
        int[] arr = {1, 1, 6, 5, 4, 3, 4, 6, 1, 7, 2, 1, 4, 9};
        int[] result = DistinctFirst(arr);

        foreach (var i in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
9
7
2
3
5
4
4
4
6
6
1
1
1
1
```

[Code on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KnFHJv)

Comment: How is that the first `6` occurence comes after three `4` in your output? (same for the `1`s)

Comment: Again, I don't see any requirement to sort. The array is arranged so that numbers that are duplicated come last. They may show up in any order.

Comment: "*my output should be
`1 2 3 4 5 6 7 9` + (duble elements in whatever order, e.g. `1 1 1 4 4 6`)*" - still 1, 4 and 6 *should* appear once on the left - **and** I feel like if *double elements [can be] in whatever order* it means the left part should be as is (i.e. sorted)

Comment: @HenkHolterman I am aware of all of the options and I chose that one for code clarity. Surely you aren't going to tell me that it is more efficient to retrieve the length and then subtract one?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily solve this problem using O(N) extra space and O(nlogn) time.
here is my python solution : the idea behind my solution is first sort the arr also keep distinct element in map or dict now you just need to apply a logic which you can easily find in gfg shifting all zero one side like wise here we have to shift distinct element one side:

```
arr = [1 ,1, 6, 5 ,4, 3, 4, 6, 1, 7, 2, 1, 4, 9]``
mp={}

for i in range(len(arr)):
    if arr[i] not in mp:
        mp[arr[i]]=1

 arr.sort()

 j = 0
 for i in range(len(arr)):
     if arr[i] in mp and mp[arr[i]]!=0:
          mp[arr[i]]-=1
          arr[i],arr[j]=arr[j],arr[i]
          j+=1
  print(arr)
```